# How to ignore the type of class field in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have the following property in my class:

```
@NotNull
@Digits(fraction = 0, integer = 2)
private Byte              value;
```

And the following code:

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<Integer>();
values.add(1);
values.add(2);
Query query = getSession().createQuery("SELECT E FROM MyClass E WHERE E.value IN (:VALUES)");
query.setParameter("VALUES", values);
query.list();
```

As you can see, the type of field "value" is Byte, whereas the parameter is a list of Integers. What should I do to tell the hibernate to get rid of ClassCastException and Ignore the type of parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly you should change your list to `List<Byte>`. As I guess you have changed it to `Integer` because of compile-time error in lines `values.add(1)`. Here you should explicitly cast this constants to `byte`:

```
List<Byte> values = new ArrayList<Byte>();
values.add((byte)1);
values.add((byte)2);
```

Comment: Sure. But the problem is that, the parameters are set via rest webservice. something like this:"@RequestBody Map<String, Object> params" and the byte value cast to integer.

Comment: @Khodabakhsh you should mention about this feature in question's body. What about this problem, you can always create new `List<Integer>` and manually add all items from `byte` list to `int` list